# How to align Aerial images from MassGIS with OSM using python?

Tags: coordinate-system, openstreetmap, pyproj, orthorectification

**MassGIS Dataset:** I'm using the [MassGIS Data: USGS Color Ortho Imagery (2013/2014)](https://docs.digital.mass.gov/dataset/massgis-data-usgs-color-ortho-imagery-20132014) aerial images of Boston. Basically, the dataset is divided into small patches of jpeg2000 images, where each of the images have a corresponding xml file. One important piece of data in the xml file is the bound of that image in latitude and longitude. They are using EPSG:26986 while reporting this. The images are ortho-rectified.

**OSM Dataset:** I donwloaded just the building polygons of Boston using the Overpass Turbo API. As far as I understand, they are denoted using WGS84 datum and the corresponding EPSG is 4326.

**What I want to do:** For some image from the MassGIS dataset, I want to draw the building polygons on top of it using python.

**What I tried:** For the given image, I retrieve the bounding latitudes and longitudes of the image from the corresponding xml file. EPSG:26986 and EPSG:4326 seems similar enough, so I don't convert one to another. Then for all of OSM building polygons that lie inside the MassGIS image bound, I find the corresponding pixel position of each node of the building polygons using a linear transformation-

```
x = (longitude - longitude_bound_min) / (longitude_bound_max - longitude_bound_min)
                                    * image_pixel_width
y = (latitude - latitude_bound_min) / (latitude_bound_min - latitude_bound_max)
                                    * image_pixel_height
```

Doing the above, I am getting a mis-alignment between MassGIS images and OSM building polygons, as you can find [here](https://image.ibb.co/jeZaLx/Screen_Shot_2018_02_27_at_9_53_29_PM.png). My understanding was that since the images are ortho-rectified, this transformation should be enough. I would be really glad if anyone gave me any hint about what I am misunderstanding here.

Edit: For one of the MassGIS aerial images, I get the following denoted as a bound for the image in the xml file-

```
<bounding>
  <westbc>-71.240667</westbc>
  <eastbc>-71.222039</eastbc>
  <northbc>+42.196636</northbc>
  <southbc>+42.182783</southbc>
</bounding>
```

There is also a corresponding .aux file for image, running `gdalinfo' on which gives me-

```
    Driver: HFA/Erdas Imagine Images (.img)
Files: 19TCG150725.aux
Size is 5000, 5000
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_19N",
    GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",
        DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
            SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-69],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["Meter",1]]
Origin = (315000.000000000000000,4674000.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.300000000000000,-0.300000000000000)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  315000.000, 4674000.000) ( 71d14'26.40"W, 42d11'46.62"N)
Lower Left  (  315000.000, 4672500.000) ( 71d14'24.68"W, 42d10'58.02"N)
Upper Right (  316500.000, 4674000.000) ( 71d13'21.04"W, 42d11'47.89"N)
Lower Right (  316500.000, 4672500.000) ( 71d13'19.34"W, 42d10'59.29"N)
Center      (  315750.000, 4673250.000) ( 71d13'52.87"W, 42d11'22.96"N)
Band 1 Block=64x64 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Description = Layer_1
  Metadata:
    LAYER_TYPE=athematic

Band 2 Block=64x64 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Description = Layer_2
  Metadata:
    LAYER_TYPE=athematic

Band 3 Block=64x64 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Description = Layer_3
  Metadata:
    LAYER_TYPE=athematic

Band 4 Block=64x64 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Description = Layer_4
  Metadata:
    LAYER_TYPE=athematic
```

Comment: I think you had better to use ogr2ogr to change coordinates of the buildings from EPSG:4326 into EPSG:26986 or use gdal_translate for the rasters.

Comment: They're not off by much (relatively), so the misalignment looks like a NAD83 <> WGS84 problem.

Comment: My bad, turns out the bounds were probably not given in NAD83 datum, but instead WGS83 datum. Do you have any idea why this misalignment might occur then?

Answer (score 1):

I think your assumption that [EPSG:26986](http://epsg.io/26986) and [EPSG:4326](http://epsg.io/4326) are "similar enough" is wrong. One is in metres and the other is in degrees.

You should use either [`gdalwarp`](http://gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) to transform the images into EPSG:4326 or [`ogr2ogr`](http://gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) to transform the OSM vectors into EPSG:26986.

Comment: Interesting point. The bounds are represented in this way-
<westbc>-71.240667</westbc>
<eastbc>-71.222039</eastbc>
<northbc>+42.196636</northbc>
<southbc>+42.182783</southbc>

Does that mean they are already represented in the WGS84 degrees?

Comment: depends on how you got the bounds - please add the gdalinfo result for one of them to your question

Comment: I did add that to the question. I suppose, in the xml they already put in the WGS84 coordinates as bounds(they don't mention it anywhere in their dataset documentation though). But in that case, I still don't understnad why I'm getting the misalignment.